# Generic Authorize Attribute multiple Roles ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I am trying to implement a generic multiple Authorize attribute which understand that every method is authorized by role that i specify OR role named "SysAdmin" that will be in all methods, Example :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Role_A,SysAdmin")]
public Method1
{
   //actions
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Role_B,SysAdmin")]
public Method2
{
   //actions
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Role_C,SysAdmin")]
public Method3
{
   //actions
}
```

I think it is not a good idea to repeat SysAdmin in all methods, is there any solution to pass it generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you always need to check for SysAdmin role we can keep it as a constant inside the attribute.

```cs
[AuthorizeUser(Role = "Role_A")]
public Method1
{
   //actions
}
```

```cs
using System.Linq;

public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{   
    public string Role{ get; set; }
    private readonly string SysAdmin = "SysAdmin"; 

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {                
            return false;
        }

        // method to get roles array by user name from db or claims
        string roles = GetUserRoles(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString()); 

        var splittedRoles = Role.split(",");
        return roles.Any(x => splittedRoles.Any(y => y == x || y == SysAdmin))      
    }
}
```

Override the following method to return the unauthorized users

```cs
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

Comment: Cannot find the httpContextBase

Comment: I guess you are missing reference to `system.web.dll`. Please add it, if it is the issue.